# Does Azure (Standard) load-balancing require two or more nodes in backend pool?

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I'm configuring/testing Azure (Standard) load balancer, currently with a backend pool that has a single VM; in the future, additional VMs will be added.

With only a single VM in the BP, I assumed my app can still be configured to use the LB.  However, I'm finding that the app is not able to connect to the VM in the BP e.g. winhttp timeout (12002).

The only reason I can think of as to why the LB is not sending traffic to the VM is because maybe there is an unwritten requirement that a backend pool is required to have at least two VMs/nodes.  I cannot find documentation that confirms or denies.

Of course I can just test myself by adding a second VM to the BP, but not quite ready to do that yet.  So thought I'd ask

FYI - the LB has two backend pools: #1 has two VMs for that component of the app, #2 has one VM for that component of the app.

#1 works fine; the LB is spreading the load across both VMs.
#2 does not work

Just really wanting to know if Azure LB can work when the backend pool has a single node, or are two or more nodes required.

Any thoughts/details on this topic?

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

> Just really wanting to know if Azure LB can work when the backend pool
> has a single node, or are two or more nodes required.

As far as I know, you can target a single VM to the backend pool. There are [SKU comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/skus#skus).

[image]

For example, I have a single VM that host a default website with port 8080, then I can configure it like this,

**Backend pool setting**

[image]

**Health probes**

[image]

**Load balancer rules**

[image]

Access the backend website via load balancer public IP address

[image]

For the error message, you may check if your configuration is well and read [troubleshoot Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot) for more details.

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept this reply. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)